# Make email in Stripe Checkout for already existing customer read-only

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm creating a Stripe checkout session (server-side) for already existing customer. According to [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create), I should pass customer Id as a `customer` parameter. Stripe internally gets the customer object and fills his email addess in the checkout UI. It works, but the email field is editable and I don't want users to be able to change their billing email. Is it possible to make this field read-only? Here my code:

```js
await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
     line_items: [{ price: stripePriceId, quantity: 1 }],
     customer: stripeCustomerId,  // here I fill the stripe customer ID of the user
     mode: 'subscription',
     payment_method_types: ['card'],
     allow_promotion_codes: true,
     success_url: `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/premium-payment-success`,
     cancel_url: `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/premium-payment-failure`
});
```

I'd really like to prevent users changing their Stripe checkout email, because knowing each user has the same billing email in Stripe would make things much easier.

**Side note:** When the user buys something for the first time, instead of `customer` parameter, I pass `customer_email` and the email is in this scenario read-only.

**Any help is appreciated!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible, but I believe it's something Stripe is considering adding.